# MarkLogic Element Security, from ambiguity to clarity

Tags: security, element, updates, marklogic

> User: **auditor**
>
> > Role: `rest-reader` `rest-writer`
> >
> > > **Path Expression**: `/national-treasure/revenue`
> > > **Permissions**:    `pii-reader ( update )`  `pii-reader ( read )`

> I confirmed that `auditor` can’t read the `/national-treasure/revenue` element. But it can delete this document:

```
Jul 06, 2020 4:48:52 PM com.fc.allegro6.DeleteDocument deleteDocument
INFO: Delete Document /national-treasure/rocky-mountains.xml
Jul 06, 2020 4:48:52 PM com.marklogic.client.impl.DocumentManagerImpl delete
INFO: Deleting /national-treasure/rocky-mountains.xml
Deleted
```

> I wonder whether a document can be safeguarded from update(delete) through element security or privilege.

> pii-reader with read permission can update protected path:
>
> > User: `auditor`
> >
> > > Role: `pii-reader`
> > >
> > > > Path Expression:`/national-treasure/revenue` **Permissions**: `pii-reader(read)`

original node:

```
     <established>1885-01-01</established>
   </highlights>
   <revenue>CAN$6 billion/annual</revenue>
</national-treasure>
```

`node-replace`:

```
let $txn := "xquery version '1.0-ml';
             xdmp:node-replace(//revenue, <revenue>CAN$7 Trillion/annual</revenue>)"
……………………………
  <user-id>{xdmp:user("auditor")}</user-id>
```

`node-replace` result:

```
     <established>1885-01-01</established>
   </highlights>
   <revenue>CAN$7 Trillion/annual</revenue>
</national-treasure>
```

Similarly, `node-delete` goes through as well.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, Element Level Security only concerns `read` access to elements and properties in protected paths. You would have to work with document-level permissions to prevent deletion in case there is PII involved.

I could imagine you have a compartmented role called `pii-updater`. Users would then need to have that role to be able to update or delete the document.

HTH!